# Android Studio "Introduce variable" feature doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

For some reason shortcut for introducing variable doesn't work. Is this a bug in Android Studio or am I doing something wrong? I can introduce variable only with mouse from the menu. But when I click Alt + Shift + L, I get this strange popup saying *Load Context. Nothing here*. I get the same behaviour on both java and kt files. It used to work in older IDE versions. More details below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I downgraded to Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 and it works fine.